# What should a software engineer's personal web page look like?

Tags: software-industry, resume, career-development, websites

I am in the process of setting up a homepage that both potential employers and colleagues can visit to learn more about me. I have decided to use `github.io` for this service, it seems pretty flexible and integrates nicely with **[Github](https://github.com/)** where most of my work is kept.

1. What types of things should be on there, shouldn't be on there?
2. How should it be formatted?
3. Do I need a picture?
4. Should my resume be a `pdf`, embedded, or both?
5. How much "personal stuff" compared to "professional stuff"
6. Any other information you think is useful when making your personal web page.

Also, if there is a good tutorial or walk-through it would be nice, but then again I tend to think thats what these Q/A sites are for :)

**Edit**

**[Here](http://jhourani.github.io/)** is what I have so far if it helps, admittedly not much as I am in the process of constructing it now.

Comment: This is slightly off topic as youre asking for example resources and how to make it look, neither of which we relaly focus on. Your part about asking *what* to put on there is, however, very relevant, if you focus on that a bit more i think this would be a good question. e.g "What information should i have available on my personal web page when looking for a job and why"

Comment: @RhysW ok I changed it, can I actually get some useful feeback for once? Other than `stackoverflow`, where I usually post, all people seem to do on these other forums is downvote and offer criticism.

Comment: Or possibly what would a hiring manager look for on a potential employees personal website?

Comment: Also, if off-topic, please explain where I can appropriately post this type of question.

Comment: @Houdini this isn't a forum, it's a Q/A site. To facilitate that, generally a question should be 1) fairly well scoped and 2) useful to future users. With respect to this topic, I think this is actually has quite a few interesting and on-topic questions but is currently really broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decide:

- what does each market segment need to see: HR, hiring manager, technical interviewers, former coworkers, current coworkers.
- what information here will be redundant with the rest of your resume versions: LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter.
- What info will be different: code samples, reports, papers
- How will these people find the site.
- What info should not be included because it will harm you in the eyes of a potential company.

While a picture is discouraged on resumes because HR doesn't want to see it, I am not sure it should be avoided on your website.  If you didn't include a picture it would be fine, they would probably not even notice.

A version of the resume that HR finds because of the link in the PDF file of your resume doesn't accomplish much, especially if the emailed one is more appropriate for the position. The PDF format makes sure they can read it, print it, download it or email it.

Will the potential readers of the site be able to access the site. Some work locations ban access to some social media.

Comment: Ty for your opinion and input. So, which version of my resume should be a PDF download? Just like a general, more generic software developer one?

Comment: You need to decide which works for you. The most expansive one would appeal the largest group of potential employers. The worst would be an out of date one.

Answer (score -3):

I have a home page under a corporate name.  I used to have an email link to it but this was a magnet for spam, so I insist that people contact me through LinkedIn.

** 1. What types of things should be on there, shouldn't be on there? **

Two of the elements on my site are demonstrations, so one can see actual executable code, and unusual solutions that I've made public.  For the most part, these are simple: I'm not really a web person so the website isn't long on fanciness. One demonstrates the rendering of tree in HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript, another shows a demonstration of a JavaScript data entry form.  There is less emphasis on sophistication then there is on functionality - these things work.

The unusual solution, in particular, is C# code for converting the old Microsoft QuickBasic MBF version of floating point to IEEE double precision.  This is something I did as part of a reverse-engineering project for data that had been building up in a file system since 1989. I published it because I couldn't find it anywhere else.  If you solve a problem no one else is willing to touch, wrap your name around it.  It's hard to argue with original material.

Working code demonstrates coding skills, original solutions are a hint you can handle unique challenges

** 2. How should it be formatted? **

It looks to me like your formatting is just right.

** 3. Do I need a picture? **

Of a portrait photo? Probably not.  Such things tend to be 'set up', and don't communicate much.  Other photos of you playing in the back yard with your dog or basking on the beach with a beer aren't really communicating much more.  Your School section mention 'we' - could you get a group picture of the people on your project in the lab where you did your work?  This would be good.

** 4.Should my resume be a [.]pdf, embedded, or both? **

At various points in the past (particularly late 1990s) one could put just about anything on the web that hinted at programming and one would get contacts.  I proved this to someone who didn't believe me - he had one semester of programming completed and was in the middle of another, and I told them people with contact him with that much alone.  After some prodding, he put something out, and sure enough, with in a week he was contacted.  When you save your .PDF, make sure it is 'web searchable'.

An embedded resume might be more interesting in tree-view format, where someone could 'plus' on a section and expand it to read details, or collapse it to view higher level summaries.

** 5. How much "personal stuff" compared to "professional stuff" **

Your page mentions travel: some employers are interested in people that know their way around Europe, South America, or Asia.  Trips to the South Pole might be interesting but won't get you any farther than NOAA. One title says 'Languages and Skills', my apologies for believing that that use of 'Languages' would be for Spanish, French, and Chinese. A better term might be 'Development Platforms'.  If you do speak something other than English, this is particularly believable if you have a section on how to install SQL Server Express on a laptop written in said language.

Comment: Hi Meredith, this is great, but it doesn't really answer the question or address even half of the 6 points the asker is looking for. In general, we try to avoid questions that simply poll the community, but we can work together as a community to make sure we look deep at these questions, answer them fully, and set the bar for what is a good answer on these types of questions, possibly preventing their closure. Hope this helps!

Comment: '1.What types of things should be on there, shouldn't be on there?' Should a programmer have demos on their site? Should a programmer demonstrate an original solution to a problem, particularly if it can't be found on the Internet anywhere else? Excuse me.

Comment: Specifically, you should edit and cover #2, #3, #4, and #5. Remember, answers on our site should be a [complete, standalone answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It may help make it more clear what you've addressed by breaking it up into sections. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @MeredithPoor ty for your advice also, I think you make some good point in there. I will change `Languages` to something like `Programming Languages` maybe...